# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on Virtual Ubuntu64bit

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to learn multithreaded and multiprocessed programming. I am very new to both multithreaded/processed programing and Ubuntu environment. I worked on the code below for a good 10 hours and fixed all errors and warnings. I started to code this with xCode and it is running perfectly and does exactly what I want it to do without any warnings or errors on that environment. But when try to compile and run on Ubuntu I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) I couldn't understand which part of the code resulting in this error. Any ideas on which part might cause the error? or why I am getting that? As I remember Linux does not have a core? Thank you so much in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pid, i, rc, pid1, counter;
char* iterator[500];
char* file[500];
enum {

    WALK_OK = 0,
    WALK_BADPATTERN,
    WALK_BADOPEN,
};

int walker(const char *dir, const char *pattern)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    regex_t reg;
    DIR *d;
    counter=0;
    if (regcomp(&reg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB))
        return WALK_BADPATTERN;
    if (!(d = opendir(dir)))
        return WALK_BADOPEN;
    while ((entry = (readdir(d))) ){
        if (!regexec(&reg, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0)){
            puts(entry->d_name);
            file[counter]=entry->d_name;
            counter=counter+1;}
    }
    closedir(d);
    regfree(&reg);
    return counter;
}


void* project_statistics(int i){

    FILE* f;
 //   size_t len;
    char* line;
    int read[3];
    int arr[1000];
    int p, m, fnl;

    int counter2=0;
    f=fopen(iterator[i], "r");

    if (f==NULL) {
        err(1, "%s", iterator[i]);

    }
    while((line=fgets((char*)read,sizeof(read),f))){

        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d",&p, &m, &fnl);
        arr[counter2]= p;
        counter2++;
    }

    int *firstHalf = malloc((counter2) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(firstHalf, arr, (counter2) * sizeof(int));

    //sort array;
    int k, l, tmp;

    for (k = 1; k < counter2; k++) {

        l = k;

        while (l > 0 && firstHalf[l - 1] > firstHalf[l]) {

            tmp = firstHalf[l];
            firstHalf[l] = firstHalf[l- 1];
            firstHalf[l- 1] = tmp;
            l--;

        }

    }

    printf("course %d project median: %d, project min: %d, project max: %d\n", i+1, firstHalf[counter2/2], firstHalf[0],firstHalf[counter2-1]);

    if(!feof(f)){
        err(1, "getIn");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void* midterm_statistics(int i){

    FILE* f;
    int read[3];
    char* line;
    int arr2[1000];

    int p, m, fnl;

    int counter2=0;

    f=fopen(iterator[i], "r");

    if (f==NULL) {
        err(1, "%s", iterator[i]);

    }

    while((line=fgets((char*)read,sizeof(read),f))){

        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d",&p, &m, &fnl);
        arr2[counter2]=m;
        counter2++;
    }
    int *firstHalf = malloc((counter2) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(firstHalf, arr2, (counter2) * sizeof(int));

    //sort array;
    int k, l, tmp;

    for (k = 1; k < counter2; k++) {

        l = k;

        while (l > 0 && firstHalf[l - 1] > firstHalf[l]) {

            tmp = firstHalf[l];
            firstHalf[l] = firstHalf[l- 1];
            firstHalf[l- 1] = tmp;
            l--;

        }

    }

    printf("course %d project median: %d, project min: %d, project max: %d\n", i+1, firstHalf[counter2/2], firstHalf[0],firstHalf[counter2-1]);
    if(!feof(f)){
        err(1, "getIn");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void* final_statistics(int i){

    FILE* f;
    char* line;
    int arr3[1000];
    int read[3];
    int p, m, fnl;

    int counter2=0;

    f=fopen(iterator[i], "r");

    if (f==NULL) {
        err(1, "%s", iterator[i]);

    }

    while((line=fgets((char*)read,sizeof(read),f))){

        sscanf(line, "%d %d %d",&p, &m, &fnl);
        arr3[counter2]=fnl;
        counter2++;
    }

    int *firstHalf = malloc((counter2) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(firstHalf, arr3, (counter2) * sizeof(int));

    //sort array;
    int k, l, tmp;

    for (k = 1; k < counter2; k++) {

        l = k;

        while (l > 0 && firstHalf[l - 1] > firstHalf[l]) {

            tmp = firstHalf[l];
            firstHalf[l] = firstHalf[l- 1];
            firstHalf[l- 1] = tmp;
            l--;

        }

    }

    printf("course %d project median: %d, project min: %d, project max: %d\n", i+1, firstHalf[counter2/2], firstHalf[0],firstHalf[counter2-1]);

    if(!feof(f)){
        err(1, "getIn");
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char k[500];

    int counter1=walker("/home/ey/Desktop/sampleFolder/", ".\\.txt");
    for (i=0; i<counter1; i++) {
        strcpy(k, "/home/ey/Desktop/sampleFolder/");
        strcat(k, file[i]);
        iterator[i]=strdup(k);
        printf("%s",iterator[i]);
    }

    printf("\nMaster is starting\n");

    pthread_t tid1[counter1], tid2[counter1], tid3[counter1];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    printf("\nslave1 start\n");
    printf("\n~Project Statistics~\n");

    sleep(2);
    for (i=0; i<counter1; i++) {

        rc=pthread_create(&tid1[i], &attr, (void*)*project_statistics,(void*)(intptr_t)i);

    }

    sleep(2);

    printf("\nslave1 done\n");


    printf("\nslave2 start\n");
    printf("\n~Midterm Statistics~\n");

    pid=fork();
    sleep(2);
    if (pid==0) {
        for (i=0; i<counter1; i++) {

            rc=pthread_create(&tid2[i], &attr,(void*)*midterm_statistics, (void*)(intptr_t)i);
        }

        sleep(2);
        printf("\nslave2 done\n");
        printf("\nslave3 start\n");
        printf("\n~Final Statistics~\n");
    }
    sleep(2);

    pid1=fork();
    sleep(2);

    if ((pid1==0)&&(pid==0)) {

        for (i=0; i<counter1; i++) {

            rc=pthread_create(&tid3[i], &attr, (void*)*final_statistics, (void*)(intptr_t)i);
        }

        sleep(2);
        printf("\nslave3 done\n");
        printf("\nMaster is done\n");
    }




    sleep(1);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: The 'core file' is a copy of the process memory plus some extra information. It's written to file and can be used to debug a program. 

If you can't find the core file, check 'ulimit -c'. You may need to change your user limit to e.g. 50000. (run the command ulimit -c 50000). 

When you have both the executable and the core file, run 'gdb exefile corefile' to start the gnu debugger. Then issue the command 'backtrace' inside gdb. That should display where your code fails, hopefully. Use the gcc options -O0 -ggdb to get debugging info.

Comment: I never used the gnu debugger before. But when i typed ulimit -c, i get a 0 is that normal? also when I typed the ulimit -c 50000 nothing showed up.

Comment: Nothing 'shows up', but the next time your program coredumps, a core file will be generated. Word of warning: Gdb is not the easiest debugger available on Linux. You may want to look for alternatives. ddd may be better.

Comment: Thank you! I have gun through the steps you mentioned and got something    __strcat_sse2_unaligned () at../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296  0x00005608e09c06ae in main() So I assume something i did in the main causes the crash but is there a way to learn the exact point?

Comment: In `gdb`, when it stops on the segfault [or when you use it to examine the core file], type `tb`. This gives you a stack traceback. Some of the frames will be your code. The one closest to the error being the usual suspect. Be sure you're compiling with `-g` [and, optionally, `-O0` vs `-O2`]

Comment: BTW, your walker() function needs some love. It cannot return a positive integer for both errors and item count. Also, there are some fixed size arrays, like 'file', which will overflow if you have too many files. Check, check and check again ;)

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, your `strcat` is faulting.

The source address is `file[i]`. `file` is a global array of `char *` pointers. But, it is [apparently] never initialized to anything.

So the `strcat` call will have a second argument of `NULL`, which causes the segfault.

This might occur if `walker` returns a non-zero value, which it would if the directory does not exist (i.e. the return is `WALK_BADOPEN`). This might explain why it works on one system but not another (i.e. the directory exists on one but not the other).

So, `walker` is using returning an error code, but `main` is using this return value as a count. This logic is incorrect. I believe you'll need to change the return value of `walker` or have `main` get the count a different way.

The easy way to fix this is to make the error codes negative values and have `main` check for this. Then, `walker` can return the count correctly.

So, if the directory does not exist, the return value is 2. The loop in `main` will fault on `file[0]` because nothing in `file` has been set to anything.

---

**UPDATE:**

> But for this time since I know the directory does exist, could I be trying to open it in the wrong way?

There is no "wrong" way to use `opendir`--it either opens or fails, which you already handle.

But, inside `walker`, you can't rely upon the `d_name` value from loop iteration to iteration, so, you have to use `strdup`.

Change:

```
file[counter] = entry->d_name;
```

Into:

```
file[counter] = strdup(entry->d_name);
```

Also, you should limit check against the maximum for `file` (e.g. currently only 500)

---

**UPDATE #2:**

In your thread functions, you were doing `fgets` into `read` [*not* a good choice because of libc's `read` function]. But, it was:

```
int read[3];
```

So, the line buffer was *only* 12 bytes long. This could cause the `fgets` to read a line as *two* partially split lines. This *might* cause the `arr` array to overflow

I changed this to:

```
char buf[1000];
```

I've combined the replicated code of the thread functions to a common one.

Note that `firstHalf` was allocated but never freed. So, it was "leaking". I added a `free` call for it.

Also note that there was no `fclose(f)` which could cause an `fopen` to return `NULL` (i.e. another source for segfault).

I've also reworked the thread join and `fork` logic and added `waitpid`. Also note the addition of `exit(0)` to the fork's child code.

As I was trying to understand things, I was simplifying things, so the following is a fair rework, and may seem a bit "alien" at first [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#if 1
#define MYDIR   "/home/ey/Desktop/sampleFolder/"
#else
#define MYDIR   "/tmp/data/"
#endif

#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (opt_dbg) \
            printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)

int opt_dbg;

int pid;
int i;
int rc;
int pid1;
int counter;

char *iterator[500];
char *file[500];

enum {
    WALK_OK = 0,
    WALK_BADPATTERN = -1,
    WALK_BADOPEN = -2,
};

int
walker(const char *dir,const char *pattern)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    regex_t reg;
    DIR *d;

    counter = 0;
    if (regcomp(&reg,pattern,REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB))
        return WALK_BADPATTERN;

    d = opendir(dir);
    if (d == NULL)
        return WALK_BADOPEN;

    while (1) {
        entry = readdir(d);
        if (entry == NULL)
            break;

        if (!regexec(&reg,entry->d_name,0,NULL,0)) {
            puts(entry->d_name);
            file[counter] = strdup(entry->d_name);
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

    closedir(d);
    regfree(&reg);
    return counter;
}

void *
thread_common(void *arg,int column)
{
    intptr_t i = (intptr_t) arg;
    FILE *f;

    // size_t len;
    char *line;
    int data[3];
    char buf[1000];
    int arr[1000];

    int counter2 = 0;

    f = fopen(iterator[i],"r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        err(1,"%s",iterator[i]);
    }

    dbgprt("DEBUG reading ...\n");
    while (1) {
        line = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f);
        if (line == NULL)
            break;

        sscanf(line,"%d %d %d",&data[0],&data[1],&data[2]);
        arr[counter2] = data[column];

        counter2++;
        dbgprt("DEBUG line %d %s\n",counter2,iterator[i]);
        if (counter2 >= 1000) {
            printf("overflow %s\n",iterator[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (!feof(f)) {
        err(1,"getIn");
    }

    fclose(f);

    int *firstHalf = malloc((counter2) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(firstHalf,arr,(counter2) * sizeof(int));

    // sort array;
    int k,
     l,
     tmp;

    dbgprt("DEBUG sorting ...\n");
    for (k = 1; k < counter2; k++) {
        for (l = k;  (l > 0) && (firstHalf[l - 1] > firstHalf[l]);  l--) {
            tmp = firstHalf[l];
            firstHalf[l] = firstHalf[l - 1];
            firstHalf[l - 1] = tmp;
            l--;
        }
    }

    printf("course %ld project median: %d, project min: %d, project max: %d\n",
        i + 1,firstHalf[counter2 / 2],firstHalf[0],firstHalf[counter2 - 1]);

    free(firstHalf);

    return (void *) 0;
}

void *
project_statistics(void *arg)
{

    return thread_common(arg,0);
}

void *
midterm_statistics(void *arg)
{

    return thread_common(arg,1);
}

void *
final_statistics(void *arg)
{

    return thread_common(arg,2);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    intptr_t i;
    char *cp;
    char krkt[500];

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'd':
            opt_dbg = 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    int counter1 = walker(MYDIR,".\\.txt");
    dbgprt("main: walker returned %d\n",counter1);
    if (counter1 <= 0)
        exit(1);

    for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++) {
        strcpy(krkt,MYDIR);
        if (file[i] == NULL)
            exit(3);
        strcat(krkt,file[i]);
        iterator[i] = strdup(krkt);
        printf("%s\n",iterator[i]);
    }

    printf("\nMaster is starting\n");

    pthread_t tid1[counter1];
    pthread_t tid2[counter1];
    pthread_t tid3[counter1];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    printf("\nslave1 start\n");
    printf("\n~Project Statistics~\n");

    //sleep(2);
    for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
        rc = pthread_create(&tid1[i],&attr,project_statistics,(void *) i);

    for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
        rc = pthread_join(tid1[i],NULL);
    printf("\nslave1 done\n");

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("\nslave2 start\n");
        printf("\n~Midterm Statistics~\n");

        for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
            rc = pthread_create(&tid2[i],&attr,midterm_statistics,(void *) i);

        for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
            rc = pthread_join(tid2[i],NULL);

        printf("\nslave2 done\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        printf("\nslave3 start\n");
        printf("\n~Final Statistics~\n");

        for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
            rc = pthread_create(&tid3[i],&attr,final_statistics,(void *) i);

        for (i = 0; i < counter1; i++)
            rc = pthread_join(tid3[i],NULL);

        printf("\nslave3 done\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
    waitpid(pid1,NULL,0);
    printf("\nMaster is done\n");

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

> Also the beginning of the main is not so clear to me, why are we waiting for a 'd' and make a switch-case, why it is needed to add argv and argc to the code? Since the code is depending on argv and argc in a way, can my way of compiling causing the problem?

The `argc/argv` code just parses option arguments. This is pretty standard boilerplate.

In this case, if you do `./main -d` it sets `opt_d`. Then, the `dbgprt` macro tests this, and if set, does a `printf`. Thus, all `printf` related to debug output were changed to `dbgprt`.

Doing so does *not* alter the program's execution, just adds the extra debug output. You can add more `dbgprt` if you wish.

And, you can add your own command line options by adding them to the `switch/case`.

This technique for "printf debugging" is quite common. I prefer it to using `gdb` where possible. Personally, I try to invoke the program using `gdb` only when I have a "severe" bug, such as a segfault. `gdb` can I identify the faulting line. Then, I add things like `assert`, debug prints, etc. to mitigate the problem beforehand.

> I kind of understand the logic but I couldn't manage to run the code. I mean it is still working on xcode.

The bugs I fixed are applicable to the `xcode` version as well.

> But in Linux it doesn't give any errors or warnings but when typed ./main I get nothing...

If you run on linux, use `-d`. Then, notice the output of the first `dbgprt` after the call to `walker`.

My best guess is that `walker` is returning a negative value (i.e. directory does not exist--the pattern is okay, so that's what's left). Or, returns 0 indicating the directory has no files, or no files that match the pattern.

The program should terminate with `exit(1)`, so check the error code (e.g. `echo $?`)

You *could* [and after thinking about it, probably *should*] change that first `dbgprt` back to a `printf`, so it always prints, even if you don't specify `-d`. That way, you won't get the "silent" failure, but the program will tell you, up front, if something's amiss.

---

One way to help debug this *is* to use `gdb`. Do `gdb ./main`. Then, do `b walker` to set a breakpoint on `walker`, Then, type `run`. `gdb` will stop the program at the first statement of `walker`.

You can then type `s` to "single step" the program. You can keep repeating this. When you have a prompt, you can gdb's `p` command to print variables. This will allow you to see what `walker` does.

When a line has a call to a `libc` function, such as `opendir`, `readdir`, `strdup`, etc. doing a `s` will try to single step these functions. Lengthy, and not so useful. So, on such a line, use `n` instead. If you do `s` by mistake, you can type `finish`.

When you think you've stepped enough, you can type `c`, which will continue program execution at full speed.

`gdb` has many commands, the above are just a few. It has inline help, so type `help` at the prompt. Or, `help b`, etc. There are many tutorials available.

Comment: But for this time since I know the directory does exist, could I be trying to open it in the wrong way?

Comment: Thank you! I made the change you mentioned above(strdup) but I am still getting segmentation fault. Since you said it might happen when there is no directory to open I double checked if I am giving the correctly formatted path to the walker function, and I am. I also tried to initialize the char* file[500] and only thing that doesn't give an error is initializing with {NULL} which doesn't make any sense to me..

Comment: I'm getting different results on my system, but that is to be expected. Can you edit your question and post a data file. Or, what the range of the values should be for the the three grade values [I can generate test files]. I'm actively editing here, and the sync/wait on threads and processes needs work. So, can you edit your question to explain the overall intent. Doing `sleep` after first pthread_create is non-deterministic. Better to loop on `pthread_join`. That makes all slave1 threads complete before starting slave2 threads. Is that what you want?

Comment: The _default_ is joinable, so not needed. I've found other potential segfault opportunities. I'm combining the thread code into a common function because the only difference is which column of data is used (i.e. 1, 2, or 3). Otherwise, all thread functions are identical and replicate each other.